# Rename security group in AD, and mapped SQL login

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

Example:

Lets say I have a group named `group_01`, the group is mapped to a SQL Server an given some rights on some stuff.

When I rename the group in Active Directory to any value, lets say `group_01_OLD`.
The group name wont change in SQL Server, it's still `group_01`

Is this normal behavior? Can I force SQL to rename the group when renamed in AD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An full answer is buried in the comments here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13766/user-windows-login-name-has-been-changed-in-ad-yet-session-in-sql-2008-profiler

Basically, a reboot of the whole server should pick up the change (assuming replication to all the DCs has already happened).

If you can't do that, you could try manually updating the name of the login:

```
ALTER LOGIN [domain\group_01] WITH NAME = [domain\group_01_OLD];
```

Answer (score 4):

To complement Gabriel’s answer. Given your scenario (you have granted permissions to the group `group_01` ), you **must** change the name in SQL using the ALTER LOGIN command

```
ALTER LOGIN [domain\group_01] WITH NAME = [domain\group_01_OLD];
```

The reason for this is that SQL Server looks for a matching login catalog views (i.e. `sys.server_principals`)  within SQL itself before asking AD. 
NOTE: When you rename a Windows login, SQL Server will verify that the new name matches the SID to verify that the login renaming is valid.

-Raul Garcia

Answer (score 1):

A reboot do not fix anything as far as I've experienced. SID is of course the same but besides the change of login with...

```
ALTER LOGIN [domain\previousgroupname] WITH NAME = [domain\newgroupname];
```

...you also need to change Security\Users for each database the login has a role in, if you want the change reflected everywhere and not having mismatches between logins and users. Can be done using Management studio, editing the group at Security\Logins and Mapping. Untick database, tick and choose role again. Or using ALTER USER but that's just a lot more typing.

```
USE [db]
ALTER USER [domain\previousgroupname] WITH NAME=[domain\newgroupname];
```